# Why can _mm_pause() significantly improve performance?

Tags: performance, assembly, x86, cpu-architecture, lockless

According to [Intel's manual (on page 112)](http://www.info.univ-angers.fr/pub/richer/ens/l3info/ao/intel_intrinsics.pdf):

> void _mm_pause(void)
>
> The execution of the next instruction is delayed an implementation
>   specific amount of time. The instruction does not modify the
>   architectural state. This intrinsic provides especially significant
>   performance gain.

That is to say:

`while (!acquire_spin_lock()) _mm_pause(); // code snippet 1`

is faster and has lower power consumption than

`while (!acquire_spin_lock()) continue; // code snippet 2`

I can understand why ***code snippet 1*** has lower power consumption than ***code snippet 2***.

What I cannot understand is:

**Why is *code snippet 1* faster than *code snippet 2*?**

Comment: This looks interesting : https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/issues/8578  "For spinlock implementations, Intel at least has a PAUSE instruction which specifically informs the CPU that this is a spinlock wait-loop, which allows it to optimize cache and memory accesses if possible to avoid memory ordering violations, requiring the CPUs to synchronize. This can be quite dramatic on older processors I believe  ....  PAUSE might also actually *delay* the CPU for this optimization to happen, where as rep nop will merely run as fast as possible."

Comment: It avoids a memory-order mis-speculation pipeline nuke (aka full clear of the pipeline, like a branch miss but worse) on the iteration that leaves the loop.

Comment: Also related: [What are the latency and throughput costs of producer-consumer sharing of a memory location between hyper-siblings versus non-hyper siblings?](//stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/78210324)

Comment: See also https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/benefitting-power-and-performance-sleep-loops with benchmarks on a Nehalem Xeon.  Also https://aloiskraus.wordpress.com/2018/06/16/why-skylakex-cpus-are-sometimes-50-slower-how-intel-has-broken-existing-code/ makes some inflammatory claims, but also quotes Intel's optimization manual re: the benefit of increasing PAUSE delay on SKL from ~10 to ~100 cycles as speeding up threaded workloads on HT systems by stealing fewer cycles from the other hyperthread.  (And causing less contention from re-reading often while spin-waiting.)

Comment: @racraman, It makes no sense to draw a distinction between PAUSE and REP NOP because they are exactly the same instruction. If you read a bit more of the thread you linked, you’ll see that the writer of that quotation retracted it.

Comment: @prl: I think (hope) they mean a CPU that doesn't recognize `rep nop` as special and just decodes it as a 2-byte NOP.  But the sentence it's part of doesn't make sense with that interpretation either.

Comment: @prl No, they aren't. One is an instruction, the other is two instructions. They have the same representation and the interpretation depends on whether or not the CPU supports PAUSE.